# How to create tmpfs folder with Docker via volume instruction?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, tmpfs

I want to create tmps volume via docker instructions in dockerfile. Is it possible to do so? Are there additional parameters which I can pass to configure volume instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Dockerfile, you can specify almost nothing about volumes or several other types of runtime configuration.  In particular there is no way to indicate a container should always run with a tmpfs mounted.

The only real Dockerfile statement about volumes at runtime is the [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) directive.  It has no configuration, only a list of directories that must have some sort of volume mounted on them.  Its direct effect is to cause an anonymous volume to be mounted on that directory if nothing else is; its indirect effect is to prevent future `RUN` directives from modifying the directory.  You rarely if ever need it.

[@AntonioPetricca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76652864) shows a `docker run --mount type=tmpfs` option, and if you want to mount a tmpfs container into an container, you *must* specify this (or a Compose equivalent) when you create it.  The target directory does not need to be a `VOLUME` directory.  There is no way to force this option in the Dockerfile.

In a more limited scope, you can run an individual Dockerfile build step with [`RUN --mount=type=tmpfs,target=/directory`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypetmpfs).  Again, the named directory won't be persisted in the image.  The mount won't last beyond that single `RUN` command though.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Yes, I think RUN command is more appropriate for me. I would also want to make directory executable so I can run files from this dir... do you know how I can do that?

Comment: The documentation doesn't suggest a mount option for changing the `noexec` Linux mount option.  That use case almost sounds like it might be a better fit for a multi-stage build than a tmpfs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/) about how to instrument a **tmpfs** volume, and here a simple example from there:

```bash
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name tmptest \
  --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Instead [this link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#tmpfs) tells you how to do the same thing [by Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#tmpfs):

```yaml
 type: tmpfs
  target: /app
  tmpfs:
    size: 1000
```